# Microsoft.vshup.server.httphostx64.exe has stopped working - Patch Failed

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I downloaded the Microsoft provided patch, to resolve this issue with the VsHub Server. I am running Visual Studio Community 2015 on a Windows 10 machine. The patch has not corrected the problem, for executing a simple Win App, with only a form and no code, it continues to crash. After stopping the execution, the VsHub stays executing in the background, returning an abort message ever 30-45 seconds. Is there any way to disable this item from executing, so I can at least write a simple application. I am relearning VB, as my skills have not been used since the Visual Studio 6 release.

The patch was http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3090034

Comment: I have had the same behavior, except I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise.  In summary, I was strongly encourage to upgrade to Windows 10 (basically told now or never) and now I cannot use Visual Studio.  This is an epic failure on Microsoft's part.  I see bug reports dating back to May on this.  If I turned out something like this, I'd be finding a job mucking out horse stalls.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, tried several patches and workarounds but it didn't work. I use windows 10 with visual studio 2015 community.

Found out that the problem was caused by a program i had installed, Lavasoft webcompanion,(read on this forum somewhere that several others had problems with programs from Lavasoft and this error) and once this was uninstalled the error left and never came back :) Didn't even need to restart my computer.

Hope this helps